# Swift: Providing a default protocol implementation in a protocol extension

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm trying to play around a bit with Swift, protocols and protocol extensions. Specifically I'm trying to provide a default implementation of a protocol in a protocol extension. This is my code:

```
protocol Proto : class {
    func someMethod() -> String
}

extension Proto {
    static func create() -> Self {
        return ProtoDefaultImpl() as! Self
    }
}

class ProtoDefaultImpl : Proto {
    func someMethod() -> String {
        return "doing something"
    }
}

let instance = Proto.create()
let output = instance.someMethod()

print(output)
```

The compiler complains on the line where I call `Proto.create()`, with the following error: error: `static member 'create' cannot be used on instance of type 'Proto.Protocol'`.

Have I missed something here? Is there any way you can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't call the method on the protocol itself, you have to call it on a type that implements the protocol. This doesn't change because there is a default implementation of the protocol in an extension. Change your type from `Proto` to `ProtoDefaultImpl` and it will work as you expect.

```
protocol Proto : class {
    func someMethod() -> String
}

extension Proto {
    static func create() -> Self {
        return ProtoDefaultImpl() as! Self
    }
}

class ProtoDefaultImpl : Proto {
    func someMethod() -> String {
        return "doing something"
    }
}

let instance = ProtoDefaultImpl.create()
let output = instance.someMethod()

print(output)
```

This outputs: `doing something`

Comment: Yes, that works. What I wanted to explore was if there was some way that users of Proto could produce an object that implements Proto without knowing which specific implementation to instantiate. Maybe some kind of Factory that produces Proto implementations would be a better fit? Anyways, thanks for answering!