# Static Member Cannot Be Used on Protocol Metatype Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a closure for a protocol type I have, but I'm getting the following error

> Static member 'menuItemSorter' cannot be used on protocol metatype 'MenuItem.Protocol'

Here's a reduced version of my code that I'm trying to run in a playground.

```
protocol MenuItem {
    var order: Int {get}
}

extension MenuItem {
    static var menuItemSorter: (MenuItem, MenuItem) -> Bool {
        return { $0.order < $1.order }
    }
}

class BigItem : MenuItem {
    var order: Int = 1
}

let bigItems = [BigItem(), BigItem()]

let sorter = MenuItem.menuItemSorter
```

I'd like to be able to have a class/static var method on MenuItem that can sort menuItems, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Providing a default protocol implementation in a protocol extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043292/swift-providing-a-default-protocol-implementation-in-a-protocol-extension)

Comment: Your particular configuration may be safe, but consider that the implementation of `menuItemSorter` is free to access other static requirements of `MenuItem`, which may not have default implementations.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Protocols don't have an accessible interface from the rest of your code.

You need to call it from an adhering type:

```
class BigItem: MenuItem {
    var order: Int = 1
}

let sorter = BigItem.menuItemSorter
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems a dumb restriction to me from Swift. Maybe I'll introduce a top-level conforming type solely for statics.

Comment: @MattD Feature not a bug. It goes against the idea of a protocol. A protocol is not a struct or class, it's a way for Types to use and declare adherence to a certain set of functionality. Allowing storage or functionality owned solely by the protocol would both break many current rules, and destroy any meaningful difference between a protocol and a class.

Comment: @PeejWeej since its static, it doesn't really imply storage in the same way as a class, its just scoping the access to a static variable or function. This would be quite nice when you have a framework providing some class `MyClass` and you also have `MyClassImpl` but would like to hide `MyClassImpl` from client code. `MyClass` could have a static function `public static func create(...) -> MyClassImpl` which actually constructs and returns the implementation, allowing the client code to not depend on MyClassImpl, but also have convenient access to a way to create one

Comment: @wfbarksdale It may not necessary imply "storage", but it definitely implies ownership. It would have to exist somewhere in the runtime, and be owned by the protocol that (currently) has 0 ownership capabilities. Allowing protocols to define logic and/or have ownership would make protocols very similar to abstract classes, rather than the special flower they are currently. Maybe it should/will be added at some point, but there may be better solutions to the problems it tries to solve (e.g. the aforementioned abstract classes). Until then it's kinda just bike-shedding :)

Comment: Since we can have default protocol implementations and computed properties in protocol extensions one would expect this as well. 
Swift evolution process proposal maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using this approach as a workaround until Swift provides this feature:

```
class MenuItemFunctions {
    static var sorter: (MenuItem, MenuItem) -> Bool {
        return { $0.order < $1.order }
    }
}

let sorter = MenuItemFunctions.sorter
```