# Providing a 'fallback protocol conformance' in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm writing a code that deals with arbitrary classes that conform to a given protocol and I want to store these classes in a `Set`. To do that, they need to conform to `Hashable`.

Obviously an arbitrary class may or may not already conform to `Hashable`; and if it doesn't conform already, I'd like to add a default conformance (which I know how to do, e.g. by using `ObjectIdentifier` or similar).

To illustrate: suppose I'm writing a protocol for an event listener and a class that uses it. Here's my non-working code:

```
protocol Listener: class {
    somethingHappened()
}

class ThingThatHasListeners {
    var listeners = Set<Hashable>()

    func addListener(listener: AnyObject) {
        if let listener = listener as? Hashable {
            // already conforms to Hashable, great!
            listeners.insert(listener)
        }
        else {
            hashableListener = someMagicThatAppliesDefaultHashable(listener)
            listeners.insert(hashableListener)
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few things about this code that are not correct; and the `someMagicThatAppliesDefaultHashable` is the bit where I'm not sure what to do.

For that part, I thought of having a proxy class that wraps the real object, that would provide `Hashable`, but I believe the proxying abilities of Swift are limited.

I've seen the question and answers at [Swift: Providing a default protocol implementation in a protocol extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043292/swift-providing-a-default-protocol-implementation-in-a-protocol-extension), but I don't think it is about exactly the same thing.

Comment: You would have to apply a protocol to all objects, but you do not know anything about their instance variables. Furthermore you want to mix objects, that have an implementation of Hashable, with other classes that have no implementation. Even if you found a way, I would imagine it would be inefficient. At best it would result in a poor design.

Comment: Yeah, the mixing of hashable objects does seem a bit off, but I think the amount of listeners is going to be always small enough that the issues of inefficiency there shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: Ultimately the problem boils down to "how do I store arbitrary objects in a set when all I know about them is that they confirm to a given protocol" - should maybe just give up on the set idea, and use e.g. ObjectIdentifier of the objects to know what is a unique listener (ie object identity).